# iPhone Loading Different Views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, interface-builder

I have to xibs, and I want to load which one the user wants in the settings.  I'm just working on actually loading them and how would this been done.

This is the function in the delegate which I think would be where this happens.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    [self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

This is the delegate header file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class myAppViewController;

@interface myAppAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    myAppViewController *viewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet myAppViewController *viewController;

@end
```

So lets say I have a xib created called modernTheme, how would I load that or the myAppViewController.  If someone could do this in a generic if statement, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like your `viewController` is being created 'in Interface Builder'. Instead of that you could create the ViewControllers yourself and add them dynamically. Your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` could look something like this:

```
UIViewController *viewController;

if (showModernTheme) { // from your configuration
    viewController = [[YourViewControllerA alloc] initWith…];
} else {
    viewController = [[YourViewControllerB alloc] initWith…];
}

// assuming YourViewControllerA + B are inheriting from UIViewController

[self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Hope that helps
–f

Comment: I am creating the xib in interface bulider, otherwise it would be way to difficult for me since there are a lot of buttons in the layout.  Is there a way to do this with creating them in interfacae builder

Comment: Yeah, sure thing. You could create a the skinned skinnedViewController when showModernTheme is set and call addSubview… and makeKey… within the if statement. In the else statement you could then just send the two messages for viewController. So you would have one ViewController created in code and one using IB.